# Установка wxPython сборкой из исходников, что нужно указать в prefix

Tags: python, wxpython, linux

В моей сборке linux папка c python находится в

```
/usr/lib
```

Я скачал: wxPython-src-2.8.8.0.tar.bz2 распаковал, потом просто делаю

```
./configure
make
make install
```

но при попытке после установки в python сделать:

```
import wx
```

у меня ошибка:

```
....
File "<stdin>", line 1, in 1
ImportError: No module named wx
```

Я давно уже не ставил ничего из исходников и не очень силён в Linux, но насколько я помню нужно при `./configure` указать `--prefix='путь'` а вот какой путь? или как-то иначе это делается Мне необходимо именно из исходников собрать Спасибо

Comment: Могу наврать, там по умолчанию вроде /usr/local, соответственно -- /usr, лучше посмотреть README или INSTALL в корне дистрибутива (но такой вариант мне не нравится). Можете завести переменную PYTHONPATH (она добавляет директории, да и не только директории, к пути поиска модулей

Comment: нее, всё равно не помогло :(

Comment: @G71 А что не помогло?

Comment: ну я пробовал --prefix "/usr" указать

Comment: Воспроизводить ситуацию у себя мне (1) лениво и (2) идея накакать в /usr у меня вообще оптимизма не вызывает. Читайте, что там в README/INSTALL. В конце-концов их пишут для того, чтобы их читали...

Answer (score 1):

для начала надо удалить то, что вы успели «разложить» по файловой системе:

```
$ sudo make uninstall
```

затем удалить собранное:

```
$ make clean
```

а после этого запускать `configure` с нужными параметрами:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr
```

и далее по списку.